# Colors inverted / negative in ubuntu all video files all video players not flash in youtube

Tags: 12.04, video, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Videos playback problem after installation of Nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126747/videos-playback-problem-after-installation-of-nvidia-drivers)

When switching to 12.04 - if playing videos - any videos avi/mkv/mpg/etc in any player 8/10 times it would come up negative until launched the nvidia x server settings.   Now all of a sudden they are always negative and launching nvidia won't fix.   removed and reinstalled nvidia and still no - rebooted before trying reinstall and after...

What gives?   and HELP!?!